# Adding tooltip to donut slices

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to add a tooltip to my donut's slices on moues over as follow:

```
var tooltip = select("g.arc--first")
    //.append("div") // if I add this div here it stops working
    .append("text")

firstSlice.append('path')
    .attr('d', coolArc(firstRadius, thickness))
    .attr('class', d => `fill_${weightScale(d.data.weight)}`)
    .on('mouseover', (d) => {
       tooltip.style("visibility", "visible")
              .text(this.nodeByName.get(d.data.name)["Short Description"])
              .style("fill", "red")
              .style("position", "absolute")
              .style("text-align", "center")
              .style("width", "60px")
              .style("height", "28px")
              .style("padding", "2px")
              .style("background", "lightsteelblue")
              .style("border", "10px")
    })
```

My goal is to have a tooltip similar to http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/a22c42db65eb00d4e369 , but right now it only shows a red text at the middle of the page. I think I need to have a new `div` but when I try to add `append("div")` it stops working and doesn't show the text anymore. How should I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tooltip from the example that you mentioned works pretty simply. It is appended as a child element for `body` (you try to append it as a child for `g` element, but you cannot append html elements into svg). So you should change you code:

```
var tooltip = select('body')
    .append('div')
    .attr('class', 'tooltip');
```

I also recommend you style this tooltip in your css (add appropriate class name and rules in your css file) you can avoid chaining many `.style` methods in this case. You should set `position: absolute;` rule - you can update `top` and `left` styles and position the tooltip where you need. Also set `visibility: hidden` rule - your tooltip should be hidden by default.

In `mouseover` event handler you need to change:

`visibility` style to show the tooltip

`left` and `top` styles to position the tooltip

`text` to update text on the tooltip

```
.on('mouseover', (d) => {
  tooltip
    .style('visibility', 'visible')
    .style('left', d3.event.pageX + 'px')
    .style('top', d3.event.pageY + 'px')
    .text(d);
})
```

In `mouseout` event handler you should just hide the tooltip:

```
.on('mouseout', (d) => {
  tooltip
    .style('visibility', 'hidden')
});
```

See simplified demo in the hidden snippet below:

```js
var tooltip = d3.select("body")
    .append("div")
    .attr('class', 'tooltip');
    
d3.selectAll('circle')
 .data(['one', 'two', 'three'])
 .on('mouseover', (d) => {
   tooltip
     .style('visibility', 'visible')
     .style('left', d3.event.pageX + 'px')
     .style('top', d3.event.pageY + 'px')
      .text(d);
 })
  .on('mouseout', (d) => {
   tooltip
     .style('visibility', 'hidden')
 })
```

```css
.tooltip {
  background-color: lightblue;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 9px;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: -50px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.js"></script>
<svg width="720" height="120">
  <circle cx="20" cy="60" r="10"></circle>
  <circle cx="180" cy="60" r="10"></circle>
  <circle cx="340" cy="60" r="10"></circle>
</svg>
```